# ajax and javascript drilldown script addition

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a make/model/engine search form, the user selects the make which then populates the model, the user selects the model and it populates the engine. The problem I have encountered is that several of the manufacturers (make) use the exact same model. The script I have chooses the engine based on the model only. I would like to modify the script so it chooses the engine based on the make AND model, this would resolve my problem. I am somewhat familiar with javascript but I am no expert, I see the ajax requests in the aircraftMakeModel.php file but do not know how to add the make to the query. I have included the three files used below. Any help is appreciated in advance.

Thanks

Tom

---

aircraftMakeModel.php

---

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#aircraftMake').change(function()
{
var make=$(this).val();
var dataString = 'make='+ make;

$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "include/getAirFrame.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
$('#aircraftModel').html(html);
}
});

});

});





$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#aircraftModel').change(function()
{
var model=$(this).val();
var dataString = 'model='+ model;

$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "include/getEngine.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
$('#engineModel').html(html);
}
});

});

});
</script>
```

---

getAirFrame.php

---

```
    <?php 
include "../connection.php";
$q = $_POST['make'];
$q = addslashes($q);

$rs=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT DISTINCT(`aircraftModel`) FROM `aircraftData` WHERE `aircraftMake` = '$q' ORDER BY aircraftModel ; ");

echo '<option value="0">Aircraft Model</option>';
 while($data = mysqli_fetch_row($rs)){


$sa=$data[0];


echo '<option value="'.$sa.'">'.$sa.'</option>';

 ?>

<?php } ?>
```

---

getEngine.php

---

```
    <?php 
include "../connection.php";
$q = $_POST['model'];
$q = addslashes($q);


$rs=mysqli_query($link,"SELECT DISTINCT(`engineModel`) FROM `aircraftData` WHERE `aircraftModel` = '$q' ORDER BY engineModel");

echo '<option value="0">Engine Model</option>';
 while($data = mysqli_fetch_row($rs)){


$sa=$data[0];
echo '<option value="'.$sa.'">'.$sa.'</option>';

 ?>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Wow, please indent your code.  O.O

Comment: Can you add the rendered html?

Comment: Sorry the file I meant to use is:

Comment: @Jamen sorry, the code is indented, this is how it rendered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send the make and model on the ajax call to get the engine something like this should work. Make the call to get the model as you do, then also add the make to the ajax request data to get the engine.

Note: not sure if this is a typo $('#marke')

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
  $('#marke').change(function() {
    
    //make id
    var id=$(this).val();
    var dataString = 'id='+ id;

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "include/getph.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html) {
        $('#model').html(html);
      }
    });

  });
});



$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $('#model').change(function(){
    
    //make id
    var id = $('#marke option:selected').val();
    
    //model id
    var id1=$(this).val();
    
    var dataString = 'id1='+ id1 + '&id=' + id;

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "include/getph2.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html) {
        $('#engine').html(html);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: My apologies I updated the code to what it should be. So using var dataString = 'make='+ make + '&model=' + imodel; should work? Can you tell me how I would update the getEngine.php script to accommodate this? Thanks - Tom

Comment: My apologies I updated the code to what it should be. So using var dataString = 'make='+ make + '&model=' + imodel; should work? Can you tell me how I would update the getEngine.php script to accommodate this? Thanks - Tom

Comment: You will need to have the engine php grab the two query string parameters sent (make and model) and do your query based on that for the engine. I don't see that file here.

Comment: Got it!  Thank you @tellez, your suggestion worked beautifully!